# Return more than one calendar at a time

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have separate calendars in a google calendar account, and when I call the calendar API I currently need to iterate every group of calendars every time I want to make a call. I have 5 calendar groups I want to get just a 'read' from and it takes around 4 seconds to ask for each group of calendars separately.

When I make the call to the calendar-api is there a way of passing all the calendars at the same time?

```
// Look for the calendars we need to check
$queryCalendars = $dbase->prepare('SELECT `calendar` FROM `googleCalanders`');
$queryCalendars->execute();

while ($row = $queryCalendars->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $checkCalandars[] = $row->calendar; // Give me an Array of all the calandars we need
}

// Check to see if we need to collect the data from the cloud or if we can use the cached version
$foundEvents=[];

foreach ($checkCalandars as $checkThisCalendar){
    // Print the next 7 events on the specific calendars.
    $calendarId = $checkThisCalendar;
    $optParams = array(
        'maxResults' => 7,
        'orderBy' => 'startTime',
        'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'timeMin' => $checkTime
    );

    $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
```

I would like to just pass the $calendarId once to the API and get it to tell me all the events in those calendars instead of doing each one, one at a time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it in the way you would like as the [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) docs say:

> Returns events on the specified calendar.

If you desire, you can fill a *Feature Request* on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906) specifying what you want and the business impact it will have on you or your organization.